# How do I make php's localeconv return the correct thousands separator

Tags: php, localization, php-7

I set my local -

`setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');`

Then try to format a big number

```
$conf = localeconv();
echo number_format(1613998, 0, $conf['decimal_point'], $conf['thousands_sep']);
```

But the number never has a thousands separator. I want `1,613,998` or `1.613.998`, but I only ever get `1613998`. `$conf['thousands_sep']` is always an empty string.

I've tried

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'fr_FR');
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
```

We're running php-7 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your locales are not installed on the server.
Run `locale -a` to list all locales available.
Then run:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

and update your locale

```
sudo update-locale
```

Comment: Thanks, you don’t know a quick way to add lots of locales do you?

Comment: you might find this snippet useful: https://gist.github.com/specialunderwear/1218856